# Creating multiple instances of websocket message broker in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-websocket

I want to create multiple instances of message broker in Spring 4. I am using the following configuration:

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/App1" >
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/path1">
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>
</websocket:message-broker>

<websocket:message-broker  application-destination-prefix="/App2">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/path2">
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

And in my controller I am autowiring SimpMessagingTemplate.

I am getting the following exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   
>  Could not autowire field:
>   org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate 
>   com.cdk.phoenix.app.controller.tools.tail.LogTailController.template;
>   nested 
>  exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   
>  qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate] 
>  is
>   defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: 
>   org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate#0,org.springframework.mes
>   saging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate#1

How can I create unique instance of `SimpMessagingTemplate` for different message brokers?

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary fix, I have added a qualifier as below:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate#1")
SimpMessagingTemplate template;
```

Everything is working as expected but one error message getting displayed in the logs :

```
*ERROR* SubProtocolWebSocketHandler: handleMessage - No session for [Payload byte[0]][Headers={simpMessageType=CONNECT_ACK, nativeHeaders={}, simpConnectMessage=[Payload byte[0]][Headers={simpMessageType=CONNECT, stompCommand=CONNECT, nativeHeaders={heart-beat=[10000,10000], accept-version=[1.1,1.0]}, simpSessionAttributes={}, simpSessionId=katcl9hg, id=2627fb55-4c8a-365c-7211-e543578e9ffb, timestamp=1438601578923}], simpSessionId=katcl9hg, id=4b4f7b0e-237a-7b3b-7d3e-247096e82b51, timestamp=1438601578924}]
```

Is there anyway to fix this error?

Thanks,
Santosh

Comment: By any chance do you remember how you fixed this?